# Integrating Enterprise Library with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

I have installed Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1. Now, I want to edit app.config file from right clicking and selecting "Edit Enterprise Library Configuration". However, I couldn't see this option. I think, Enterprise Library is not integrated with my Visual Studio 2010.

How can I fix that? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the overview at [Enterprise Library 4.1 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6228), only Visual Studio 2008 and 2008 SP1 are supported. You can still launch the configuration editor from your start menu and open the file manually, or you can upgrade to Enterprise Library 5.0 which does support Visual Studio 2010.